# using z-index in correct way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I want to create a simple slider like the one I ve shown in the pic.. I have two divs wrapper 1 and wrapper2 separated by a margin of 20px,
I have a button in wrapper 1 clicking on which a new div should come down sliding which should come in front of wrapper 1 and 2,

The code that Ive used is

```
<div id="wrapper1" style="width:960px; height:200px;z-index:100;">
<a href="#" class="clickMe">
   <div id="tab1">
   </div>
</a>
<div id="slider" style="width:400px; height:100px; z-index:999;">
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2" style="width:960px; height:200px; z-index:100;">
</div>
```

and the script looks like

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $("#slider").css({"display":"none"});
 $(".clickMe").click(function()
 {
 $("#slider").slideDown("slow");
 }
 );
 });
```

With this code, what I get is the slider window comes sliding down by pushing wrapper2 downwards instead of coming in front.what could be the issue?

Comment: NB: The pic that Ive uploaded is the way I want my website to be..

Comment: I am sorry I meant its edited...I was nt talking abt the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VF7tp/3/) together.

Here is the relevant code:
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div class="clickMeWrapper">
    <a class="clickMe" id="tab1" href="#">Click Me!</a>
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clickMeWrapper">
    <a class="clickMe" id="tab1" href="#">Click Me!
    </a>
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
</div>​
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").hide();
    $(".clickMeWrapper").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).children(".slider").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

If something's not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Thnx...this one wrkd... I ve one more doubt... we use "#" for href link, so when we click on the button, the hash symbol gts attached to the url.. So do I prevent that frm hpning??

Comment: I have edited the fiddle and the code (jQuery part). This should work. Please mark this answer as correct if it is so.

Comment: One more thing, Is it possible to position the slider?? IVe tried left and top, bt it doesnt wrk..

Comment: What do you need. Relative positioning or absolute? Absolute positioning is already working.

Comment: I mean I want the opening slider a lil bit lower from the button,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VF7tp/4/ To edit the distance between the slider and the button: edit the 'top' value of .slider.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `position:absolute;` to "slider", and set its position.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your `slider` outside the wrapper elements otherwise the parent child relationship overrides some formatting rules like z-index. `position:absolute` and other css attributes should be set by jQuery automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need an absolute position for z-index to work.